# send parameter post vueJS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, request

i have a problem when iám sending a parameter with axios vueJS. Always, my script returned error 500 because index is not defined and i don´t know why. Also, when i´m traying to do click in button, first time, don´t work, and second axios to do two petitions. i attached my actual code.

Thanks for help

first i need bono type, for get this, i´m doing:

```
(".contratar").on("click", function(e){
                var bono = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text();
```

after i answerd that value is and i´m starting with axios request.

```
if(bono == 1){
     let url = "/contrarBono30Min";
     let bono = "Bono30Min";
     axios.post(url, { bono: bono } )
          .then((response) => {
              console.log(response);
           });
}
```

**in my controller:**

```
    public function contrarBono30MinHome(){
        $usuario = \Auth::user()->id;
        $bono = $_GET["bono"];

        $precioBono = \DB::select("SELECT precio FROM bonos WHERE codBono = '1'");

}
```

**my vue components**

```
<tr v-for="data in bonosDisponibles" :key="data.id">
            
                <td>{{ data.codBono }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.tipo }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.minutos }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.precio }}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger contratar" @click="contratar">Contratar</button></td> 
            </tr>
```

**contratar function**

```
contratar: function(){
            $(".contratar").on("click", function(e){
                var bono = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text();

                if(bono == 1){
                    let url = "/contrarBono30Min";
                    let bono = "Bono30Min";
                    axios.post(url, { bono: bono }
                            )
                            .then((response) => {
                                console.log(response);
                            });
                }

                if(bono == 2){
                    let url = "/contrarBono1H";
                    axios.post(url, {bono:Bono1H})
                            .then((response) => {
                                console.log(response);
                            });
                }

                if(bono == 3){
                    let url = "/contrarBono5h";
                    axios.post(url, {bono:Bono5H})
                            .then((response) => {
                                console.log(response);
                            });
                }

                if(bono == 4){
                    let url = "/contrarBono10H";
                    axios.post(url, {bono:Bono10H})
                            .then((response) => {
                                console.log(response);
                            });
                }

                if(bono == 5){
                    let url = "/contrarBono24H";
                    axios.post(url, {bono:Bono24H})
                            .then((response) => {
                                console.log(response);
                            });
                }

            });
```

In web browser console i have this:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500

Access to XMLHttpRequest at '' (redirected from '') from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

Comment: You `POST` to the script but use `$_GET["bono"]` (which you don't even use)

Comment: @kerbh0lz thanks for your response. Yes i show it after ask my question. I changed this, but i have this problem again

Comment: Can you just post the screenshot of the API endpoint page through network. It might display error.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi thaks for your response i think taht i revole my problem. I receive my parameter with request, not post or get. but now i have a problem with CORS. my app is in xampp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For send parameter in POST URL

```
.post(url, { params: { codigo: codigoAsistencia } })
```